# Dragging a path using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a case where I am creating a view pane, paths "inside" it. To give the impression the paths are inside I am clipping them. I would also like to be able to drag these paths. The usual suggestions is to use SVG `transform` attribute. But this presents two problems:

- clipped paths stay that way, while dragging only on partial paths are shown
- dragged paths "float" outside of the given pane.

Complete [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsjsu7nt/14/).

The data is:

```
var outlines = [
[{ "x": 100.0, "y": 100.0}, {"x": 200.0, "y": 100.0}, {"x": 200.0, "y": 200.0}, {"x": 100.0,"y": 200.0}, {"x": 100.0, "y": 100.0}],
[{ "x": -100.0, "y": 200.0}, {"x": 100.0, "y": 200.0}, {"x": 100.0, "y": 300.0}, {"x": -100.0,"y": 300.0}, {"x": -100.0, "y": 200.0}],
];
```

I create the paths like this:

```
layout
.selectAll('.instance')
.data(outlines)
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('class', 'instance')
.attr('d', function(d) { return line(d); })
.call(drag);
```

And the drag is:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.origin(function(d) {
  return {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
})
.on("dragstart", function(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
})
.on("drag", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .classed("dragging", true)
    .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')'; });
})
.on("dragend", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .classed("dragging", false)
    .attr('transform', null);
});
```

I think I would like to actually move the paths to the new location. But I am not sure how to manipulate the data with the d3.event offsets. How do I do that? Or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Do you want to do something like this? http://bl.ocks.org/mccannf/1629464

Comment: Yes, mostly, this example is using `rect` which is "easy" to do by just updating x/y attributes. I need to have a path since my objects could be more complex than the rect I have in the example. How do I update the path? I had noticed that panning/zooming updates the paths. How?

Answer (score 1):

To work properly, the `transform` must be strictly inside the `clip-path` (or to put it in another way, if an element has a clip-path and a transform attributes, then the coordinates of the clip-path are shifted just like the rest of the object.

The easy way to solve this in your case is to wrap your rectangles inside clip-path'd groups:

```
layout
.selectAll('.instance')
.data(outlines)
.enter()
.append("g")    //this group defines the clipping
.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
.append('path') //this path can be moved around
.attr('class', 'instance')
.attr('d', function(d) {
  return line(d);
})
.call(drag)
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/xhfcdbb7/

I've also removed all other references to clip-path (this way, the group remains clip to the same absolute rectangle, whether it is dragged or not)